# A route for Grape: either a specific string or an of array of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to create a route for the Grape gem so that a route accepts either an array of strings or a single string with a specific pre-defined value. From the documentation it's not clear how to do that.

Your suggestions?

UPDATE:

I want `status` to be passed either a single value `status1` or as a array where values can be arbitrary and unknown. I combine these?

```
params do
  requires :status, type: Symbol, values: [:status1]
  requires :status, type: Array[String]
end
```

Comment: Be more specific. It's not clear what you really want to do. Do you want to handle multiple routes in a single method?

Comment: @Marlon, I don't know how to explain that even more simple.

Comment: Give us an example. Add in your question the code you've written and that isn't working. Or add a code illustrating what you want to do.

Comment: @Marlon, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Okay. It's up to you. The way you stated your question, I can't understand your needs, therefore I'm unable to help you.

Answer (score 2):

A parameter must be declared only once in the **params** block. If you declare it twice then only one will be used by Grape. In your case, there're two options to solve your problem.

First option: declare two parameters and define them as mutually exclusive. It means that the user will be able to inform only one of them.

```
params do
  requires :status1, type: Symbol, values: [:status1]
  requires :status2, type: Array[String]
  mutually_exclusive :status1, :status2
end
```

Second option: declare only one parameter and set its type to **Object**. In the method's body, check if it's an Array or a String. If it's a String, verify if it has the correct values.

```
params do
  requires :status, type: Object
end
get 'testing' do
    if params[:status].class.name.eql? "Array" then
    elsif params[:status].class.name.eql? "String" then
    end
end
```